# Copy data from a google sheet to the last row in another google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have two google sheets. I want to copy the data from a certain tab in the first google sheet ( source) to the second google sheet ( target). The most important thing is that I want to paste the data in the first new row after the old data not overwrite the old data.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent override use appendRow([])
See in [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object))